# Mongoose schema saving nested schema as id only, not as object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, ejs

I have 2 mongoose schemas: The first, "feedback":

```
var feedbackSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    author: String,
    student: String,
    gender: String,
    content: String
});
```

is a member, of the second "aClass":

```
var aClassSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    serialNumber: String,
    title: String,
    classDescription: String,
    curriculumVersion: String,
    scheduledDateTime: String,
    feedbacks: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Feedback"
        }
    ]
});
```

In an ejs file, I'm trying to access the author of the feedback like so:

```
    <div style="width: 700px; margin: 50px auto; background-color:lightgrey; border: 3px solid black">
        <% aClass.feedbacks.forEach(function(feedback){ %>
        <p style="margin: 10px"><strong><%= feedback.author %> - <%= feedback.content %></strong></p>     
        <% }); %>
        <p>
   </div
```

But I can't because in examining the "aClass" object, I get the following:

{ feedbacks: **[ 5e109f3fd1a6540cd8286628, 5e10b1f64c82be15a9d9bda1, 5e10b23f38800515b7415b4a ]**, _id: 5e109f3fd1a6540cd8286626, serialNumber: '12455223', title: 'Todays Class', classDescription: 'desc', curriculumVersion: '2', scheduledDateTime: 'Jan 01 04:00 AM', __v: 3 }

So it's only saving the object id's, so I can't access the author or comments. Any ideas? I'm seeing a lot of related questions but not one that has the answer I'm looking for, so I apologize in advance if this already exists somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

You can too populate with aggregate, like this:

`db.aclassModel.aggregate([
 {
        $lookup: {
          from: "*youfeedbackcollection*",
          foreignField: "_id",
          localField: "feedbacks",
          as: "fee"
        }
      }
]`

Answer (score 0):

OK so I just realized I have to use "populate" as in the following:

```
AClass.findById(req.params.id).populate("feedbacks"), function(err, aClass){}...
```

Of course I found it right after I posted the question...